# How to write hql query or criteria query to fetch latest records based on timestamp

Tags: hibernate, hql, criteria

Hi i new to ORM technology So can one help how to write hql or criteria query to fetch latest  records based on timestamp.
here Eventdata domain property names will be same as column names mentioned below.
I have table like this
Eventdata:

```
AccountId   DeviceId    timestamp   Address
fuel    mdemo143    1389716109  Bangalore Road, Rajendra Nagar, Mysore, Karnataka
fuel    mdemo469    1389757662  Bharath International Travels, Diwan's Road
fuel    mdemo731    1390179714  Ring Road, Hebbalu, Mysore,
fuel    mdemo143    1390148225  Gandhinagar, Mysore


fuel    mdemo469    1389757682  Bharath International Travels, Diwan's Road
fuel    mdemo469    1389759662  Bharath International Travels, Diwan's Road
fuel    mdemo731    1390179714  Ring Road, Hebbalu, Mysore,
fuel    mdemo731    1390279714  Ring Road, Hebbalu, Mysore,
```

I need output table will be like below:

```
AccountId   DeviceId    timestamp   Address

fuel    mdemo143    1390148225  Sun, 19 Jan 2014 16:17:05 GMT   Gandhinagar, Mysore


fuel    mdemo469    1389759662  Wed, 15 Jan 2014 04:21:02 GMT   Bharath International Travels, Diwan's Road
fuel    mdemo731    1390279714  Tue, 21 Jan 2014 04:48:34 GMT   Ring Road, Hebbalu, Mysore
```

please help me .Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `ORDER BY` and [`Query#setMaxResults`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Query.html)

Something along the lines of

```
queryString = "SELECT e FROM Eventdata e ... ORDER BY e.timestamp";

session.createQuery(queryString).setMaxResults(10);
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get records based on `timestamp` you can use something like:

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<String> getData(Date d){
    Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT e FROM EventDate e WHERE e.timestamp > :d ORDER BY e.timestamp");
    query.setParameter("d", d);
    List<String> queryResults = query.getResultList();
    return queryResults;
}
```

This will return the records after the specified `timestamp`